# How do I create a non-URL clickable link in Java source file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am experimenting with Markdown and AsciiDoc to see if we can provide richer docs-as-code than we do today.   This is very promising.

It is possible to link from an AsciiDoc file to a Java source file, so the reader can navigate the rendered version directly.   It is also possible to put a URL in a comment in a Java source file which can be Ctrl-Click'ed to go there.

Is there a special syntax that is understood by IntelliJ so it can be used in a similar way to easily navigate from a Java source file (Groovy and Kotlin are also interesting) to a non-source file?   I'd prefer one that can be put on any comment like an URL, but if Javadoc can do it that is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You can link a file the same way you would link anything else.
For example, I have the following line in an Asciidoc file in my project:

```
link:./src/main/java/javax0/jamal/test/examples/Array.java[Array.java]
```

in an Asciidoc file edited using the IntelliJ asciidoctor-based plugin will show you on the right pane a link. If you click on it in the editor, it will open the Java file.

The other way around, having a link in a Java comment pointing to a non-java file: I am not so sure. If you look at the IntelliJ ticket

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206181749-java-Viewing-links-in-source-code-comments

from 2014 it is already commenting on it.

Comment: I have the AsciiDoc->Elsewhere bit (but didn't know the link: trick).  I'll have a closer look at the ticket.  Thanks